# What is the best way to get a section of a website to break the grid and stick to one side of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

I am working on front-end development on a Shopify site and am having trouble getting a section to "break the grid" to span to the side of the viewport, with the otherside spanning slightly outside of the grid in the other direction. It's kind of difficult to explain, so I am attaching images.

[design I'm looking to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkQyn.png)

Can see current site here: 
https://0rmwb5xh1kvogaal-17179607104.shopifypreview.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css properties on `.feature-row__text` class to achieve your desired result.

```
.feature-row__text {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 570px;
    right: 170px;
}
```